# MVC on android: Model change and animation

Tags: android, model-view-controller

After some thinking/reading (especially [following](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/07/android-architecture-part-10-the-activity-revisited/) series) I came to accept the following general rules for implementing MVC:

- *Model* - set of simple dummy *Value Objects*, responsible for keeping the state. Model classes are *Observable* and notify *Observers* - i.e. views when changed. Model code could be android agnostic.
- *View* - classes able to keep/update its visual state - based on `android.view.View/ViewGroup` family - by inheritance or composition. *View* classes are *Model*-aware, they receive update of *Model's* state and re-draw accordingly. All user-input  listening code is delegated to *Controller*.
- *Controller* - all user-input processing code in your activity/fragments. Controller updates the *Model*, which in turn, will trigger subscribed *View* update.

Sounds simple and certainly doable in most cases.

Now, consider for example:
*Controller/Activity* keeps track of 2 *Model* objects `model1` and `model2` and changes them based on some application logic.

*View* receives updates from objects `model1` and `model2` independently as per design above. 

**Now, suppose** the *View* wants to show animation based on *mutual transition* of both `model1` and `model2` for which it needs to know changes of *both* objects at one time, or as a single event.

What would be recommended way of doing it, keeping mvc design above in place?

I thought about options:

1. Have a "SmartModel" which encapsulates both `model1` and `model2`, make the mutual changes/transition and inform the *View*. I don't like this approach because *Model* becomes not really just "dumb" state representation, but also drags some application logic from *Controller*.
2. Have *Controller* inform the *View* about the changes it did on both `model1` and `model2`. In that case neither *model1* nor *model2* need to implement ability to notify the *View*, i.e. there is no link between *Model*->*View* anymore.
3. May be there is much better option / I am missing something.

Any insightful suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option 2) is similiar with MVP pattern, controller is kind of presenter to change the view for model.

[Model View Controller, Model View Presenter, and Model View ViewModel Design Patterns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42830/Model-View-Controller-Model-View-Presenter-and-Mod)

If you want to follow the strict MVC way, maybe you need to fire some change event to notify the View observers, so they can know what and how exactly the model changes, so they can do partial refresh and animation.